# Get only json from bitbucket api response

Tags: php, json, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

This is my code:

```
$curl1 = curl_init();   
$url = "https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/webesian/jobmarkt/pullrequests/";
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "***:***");
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($curl1);
```

My problem is that the output variable is not json only. There's some other crap inside. How can i extract only the json from the response?

Comment: Since you posted your credentials on SO, you might to change your password on Bitbucket.

Comment: Oh thank you! But I've already changed it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to true, so it will output the header info as part of the response.
Removing that or setting it to false should solve the problem